# Gerar em PDF latex o BEKK e diagnoseBEKK do pacote ‘mgarchBEKK’

Tags: r

Estou querendo gerar em PDF no latex as funções BEKK e diagnoseBEKK do pacote mgarchBEKK, só que ele sai todo desconfigurado. Segue do dados:

```
> head(LOG1)
     [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 3.129256 3.288402
[2,] 3.148093 3.292126
[3,] 3.151220 3.284664
[4,] 3.145901 3.280911
[5,] 3.140324 3.295837
[6,] 3.143793 3.295837 

> dput(head(LOG1, 20))
structure(c(3.12925604926495, 3.14809347817882, 3.15122000536595, 
3.14590053886684, 3.14032413879594, 3.14379279514427, 3.15001885787015, 
3.15575581137615, 3.1871339647665, 3.17698029293942, 3.1650185553098, 
3.15712199430691, 3.15808523968012, 3.1424437880591, 3.11208598177176, 
3.12253114789199, 3.15877485557127, 3.16054905970894, 3.17276954280673, 
3.18961151256573, 3.28840188751681, 3.29212628660779, 3.2846635654062, 
3.28091121578765, 3.29583686600433, 3.29583686600433, 3.29620716780452, 
3.30688670219091, 3.32143241319329, 3.31418600467253, 3.29953372788566, 
3.31600253559892, 3.31418600467253, 3.30027146307219, 3.2846635654062, 
3.28840188751681, 3.30431930668567, 3.30431930668567, 3.34215484102837, 
3.33932197794407), .Dim = c(20L, 2L))
```

Quando eu gero a função BEKK:

```
> estimated1 <- BEKK(as.matrix(LOG1),c(1, 1))
H IS SINGULAR!...
H IS SINGULAR!...
H IS SINGULAR!...
H IS SINGULAR!...
H IS SINGULAR!...
```

e a função diagnoseBEKK, eu gostaria de gerar em tabela stargazer os "C estimates", "ARCH estimates" e "GARCH estimates"

```
> diagnoseBEKK(estimated1)
Number of estimated series :  5282 
Length of estimated series :  2641 
Estimation Time            :  6.374574 
Total Time                 :  7.716886 
BEKK order                 :  1 1 
Eigenvalues                :  13.62364 1.016955 0.7921524 0.09844105 
aic                        :  -206.238 
unconditional cov. matrix  :  677.4441 -669.5645 -669.5645 661.1839 
var(resid 1 )                :  0.5140241 
mean(resid 1 )               :  0.6797914 
var(resid 2 )                :  0.4907388 
mean(resid 2 )               :  0.6919167 
Estimated parameters       :

C estimates:
          [,1]        [,2]
[1,] -0.06893851 -0.07384558
[2,]  0.00000000  0.01378535

ARCH estimates:
         [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  0.3166768  1.250476
[2,] -1.2402237 -2.175200

GARCH estimates:
        [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -1.726880 -1.3451395
[2,]  1.316612  0.9358533

asy.se.coef                : 

C estimates, standard errors:
       [,1]         [,2]
[1,] 0.03257374 0.0331921785
[2,] 0.00000000 0.0004459779

ARCH estimates, standard errors:
        [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.1476386 0.1501182
[2,] 0.1460898 0.1473559

GARCH estimates, standard errors:
        [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.5575840 0.5634912
[2,] 0.5514318 0.5570802
```

E ainda pede para clicar em "continue", que eu também gostaria de tirar para não atrapalhar na hora de gerar o PDF

```
Called from: diagnoseBEKK(estimated1)
Browse[1]> c
Called from: diagnoseBEKK(estimated1)
Browse[1]> c
```

Comment: Em vez de postar as funções de um pacote que nós podemos obter, por favor **edite a pergunta** com as intruções que tentou, como chmaou essas funções e com a saída de `dput(dados)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(dados, 20))`? Nota: `dados` é o nome da base, por exemplo de um data.frame.

Comment: Ok Rui, fiz as devidas alterações.

Comment: Muito melhor. Mas falta o código, como está a usar as funções que estão a causar problemas, como está a chamá-las.

Comment: Acho que coloque a informação que solicitou, se entendi bem. Obrigado Rui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode criar uma tabela latex para cada matriz de estimativas com a seguinte função. Não vou usar o pacote `stargazer` mas sim o pacote `xtable`, que é mais simples e que para este problema chega bem.

A saída da função é uma lista com as tabelas latex, uma por cada membro da lista.

```
library(mgarchBEKK)
library(xtable)


mgarchBEKKlatex <- function(x, digits = 4, ...){
  out <- vector("list", length = sum(c(1, x$order)))
  out[[1]] <- xtable(x$est.params[[1]],
                     caption = "C estimates:",
                     digits = digits, ...)
  if (x$order[2] > 0) {
    caption <- "ARCH estimates:"
    for (count in seq_len(x$order[2])) {
      out[[count + 1]] <- xtable(x$est.params[[count + 1]],
                                 caption = caption,
                                 label = paste("order:", count),
                                 digits = digits, ...)
    }
  }
  if (x$order[1] > 0) {
    caption <- "ARCH estimates:"
    for (count2 in seq_len(x$order[1])) {
      out[[count2 + count + 1]] <- xtable(x$est.params[[count2 + count + 1]],
                                 caption = caption,
                                 label = paste("order:", count),
                                 digits = digits, ...)
    }
  }
  out
}

estimated1 <- BEKK(LOG1, c(1, 1))

tabelas <- mgarchBEKKlatex(estimated1)

tabelas[[1]]
#% latex table generated in R 3.6.1 by xtable 1.8-4 package
#% Mon Aug 12 20:28:18 2019
#\begin{table}[ht]
#\centering
#\begin{tabular}{rrr}
#  \hline
# & 1 & 2 \\ 
#  \hline
#1 & 6.1491 & 6.4497 \\ 
#  2 & 0.0000 & 0.0040 \\ 
#   \hline
#\end{tabular}
#\caption{C estimates:} 
#\end{table}
```